Forming an O.D.E for $y=A\sin(Bx)+B\cos(Bx)$


Forming an O.D.E for $y=A\sin(Bx)+B\cos(Bx)$, Where $A$ and $B$ are the arbitrary constants.


My efforts:
We have $$y'=AB\cos(Bx)-B^2\sin(Bx)$$
Also $$y''=-AB^2\sin(Bx)-B^3\cos(Bx)=-B^2y$$
Now I am helpless to eliminate the constants $A,B$

Why would you be able to eliminate A and B?

Are you looking for an o.d.e. for which all functions of the form are solutions, or an o.d.e. for which the functions of the given form are the only solutions?

You already derived the O.D.E: $y'' = - B^2y$.
Note that $B = y(0)$

As per my knowledge, Is not the O.D.E should have same order as there are number of independent arbitrary constants?

@LifeIsMath The constants are arbitrary. An ODE has infinite number of solutions. To get a unique solution you have to fix them by the two boundary conditions, see my answer here .

To eliminate $B$ ...
$$
y'' = -B^2y
\\
\frac{y''}{y} = -B^2
\\
\left(\frac{y''}{y}\right)' = 0 .
$$
To eliminate $A$ ...
$$
y'=AB\cos(Bx)-B^2\sin(Bx)
\\
\frac{y'+B^2\sin(Bx)}{B\cos(Bx)} = A
\\
\left(\frac{y'+B^2\sin(Bx)}{B\cos(Bx)}\right)' = 0 .
$$

But the order of the equation should be $2$ only right

All of the functions in the question statement are solutions of this o.d.e., but there are other solutions, too, e.g., constants. If you're looking for an o.d.e. whose solutions are those functions (and no others), that could be clarified in the question statement.
